# Retrieving maximum supported texture size in libGDX

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I use this code in libGDX to get the maximum supported texture size:

```
private static int getMaxTextureSize () {
    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.newIntBuffer(16);
    Gdx.gl.glGetIntegerv(GL20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, buffer);
    return buffer.get(0);
}
```

Can I rely on the value returned by this function? For example, if the function returns 2048, does that mean that I can safely use 2048x2048 textures?

**Is this method reliable?**

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by reliable? You ask OpenGL how large textures can be, why would it return wrong data?

Comment: I'm pretty newbie in graphics and opengl. I've heard that opengl may sometimes return a wrong value, so I'm just making sure, because my game might depend on this value, and I don't want it to crash.

Comment: By the way, the "grain of salt" thing in the linked thread pushed me to write this question.

Comment: Afaik, OpenGL never returns wrong values. You should just not confuse what you query: `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` returns the maximum size the implementation can handle. It does **not** tell you whether you can allocate a texture of that size in the current state (e.g. due to memory limits)

Comment: @BDL Ok I get it, so I must query something else to determine if there is, for example, enough gpu ram space. If that's the case, please write your second comment as an answer so I can upvote and accept.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible in OpenGL (also because implementations are free to store data in every memory they want; no guarantee that something is really stored in GPU memory). There might be some vendor specific extensions that tell you how much memory is used, but as I said, you cannot judge from that whether a texture can be allocated.